# Automation testing stripe Google and apple pay

Tags: reactjs, webdriver, stripe-payments, applepay, google-pay

I'm trying to write automated tests for scenarios where customer can pay using apple pay or Google pay. We use stripe as our payment processor. When I click on Apple pay or Google pay it a new browser secure element pops and I couldn't find a way to interact with them. Looking for help as I'm stuck here.

Comment: Hey there! I see you tagged the question with "webdriver", but if you could explain more about how you're running your tests, that may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact with those by design as that would be a security risk. Instead you should look at mocking the responses from those instead.

In the case of Stripe's PaymentRequest API you should see if you can mock the "paymentmethod" event: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_request/events/on_paymentmethod